Button is unclickable when using Playwright to trigger it
It's written in Python playwright code,I can't click on certain buttons
Is there any way to solve it?
<button id="btnConfirmInvoice" class="btn btn-default" data-po-seq="88902667">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;거래명세서확인
</button>

Click on this code to open a selection window
The confirmation/cancellation button appears again.
The interesting thing about this code is that if you work with selenium, you can click it, but if you do playwright, you can't.
I want to work on this because playwright is in full headless mode.
<a href="javascript:selReadyDelivery('OrderDeliveryList')" class="btn-c"><span>선택주문 발주확인</span></a>

It's this phrase.
Come to think of it, this is also the code that shows the selection box.
I can't click it.
Can anyone solve it?
I've tried every method, including locator, but my knowledge is limited.

The button should be clickable. There shouldn't be anything preventing you from clicking it, like no physical force acting on your fingers.

await page.locator('#btnConfirmInvoice').click()

Please share a [mcve]. The site may have arbitrary behavior beyond the simple HTML shown--an iframe, a bot detection block, etc.

@Klim Bim // The problem is that I don't make it automated, I just open the chrome browser and work manually, but I can't click on the 1st or 2nd button.

@AquaRius so then why do you use Playwright? I don´t get the relation to PlayWright. Like ggorlen mentioned, please share a minimal reproducible example.

I solved it! Thank you for the comments!!!
